# 2 horizontal colors in background, one of them is wider that the other, please see the photos

Tags: html, css

```css
.u-layout-carousel .u-over-slide {
  height: Auto;
  width: auto;
  position: fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffcc00 70%, #64482c 30%);
  top: 210px;
  left: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="u-over-slide u-valign-middle u-over-slide-3">
  <p class="u-gallery-heading u-text-white">rdfghfgh</p>
  <p class="u-gallery-text u-text-body-alt-color" style="margin-top: 21px; background-image: none;"></p>
</div>
```

I need to add hover box over a slider in my website , note that I do not want to edit the HTML . I need just to modify the code in css

and I need this box to have two colors aligned horizontally , I achieved that with the following code

But in the same time , I need the second color to be wider that the first one (the upper )

[like this exactly what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tbFA.png)

Please note , I want to have one element only , and I can not edit the HTML SO , the change will be only in the CSS....

[but with my code , I have this ,my code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOcml.png)

[G-Cyrillus , here what I have , thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPg4U.png)

I make a modification on the html , I can not edit it since I use a web builder , so please give me a solution  , because the below answer is wrong

Comment: ad your HTML too , so we see what you've done in action ;)

Comment: please add your working code snippet. Will be easier to understand existing structure.

Comment: Sorry guys , I am so startup in this , can you explain more how can I do it?

Comment: h3 and p can receive two different colors ;)

Comment: could you please add more html? it would be nice to see what element this is in

Comment: where could I find the full HTML  file ?

Comment: We have no idea untill we know what tool you use and if we can have access to its code if it is open source. You did provide the code at first , we are surprised of that new issue now ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is much more simple than you think. 2 containers = 2 background-colors ;)

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1012/600/400) center center / cover;
}
div {margin-top:1em;}
h3,
p {
  padding: 0.5em 1rem;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  color: white;
  background: #ffcc00;
}

p {
  background: #64482c;
}

/* for the fun and curiosity*/
div {
filter:
drop-shadow(0px 2px white) 
drop-shadow(-2px 0px white)
drop-shadow(0px -2px white)
drop-shadow(2px 0 white)
```

```html
<div class="u-over-slide u-valign-middle u-over-slide-3">
  <h3 class="u-gallery-heading u-text-white">hello i am the title</h3>
  <p class="u-gallery-text u-text-body-alt-color">hello i am the paragraph hello i am the paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @sameee1478 it works for the bgcolor, for the font-size , line-height, etc... it's yours .

Comment: thanks again , please check the photo , I think I made a mistake , and can you guide me how to edit the HTML file , if needed

Comment: you need to add styles only for h3 and p , using their class names and last in your css files. mind also the selector specifity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity I'm afraid, you will have to learn the basis before to really go further :(

Comment: thanks , but how to find the HTML file in order to edit ?

Comment: no idea about how  your site is coded . is it a cms open source or not, else  .... Sorry, i do not do online lessons

Comment: guys , how can I add this ,                                                                                       
    <div class="u-over-slide u-valign-middle u-over-slide-3">
  <h3 class="u-gallery-heading u-text-white">hello i am the title</h3>
  <p class="u-gallery-text u-text-body-alt-color">hello i am the paragraph hello i am the paragraph</p>
</div> I could not find the file that contain the element

Comment: @sameee1478 What web builder are you using ? any url for this tool you use ? Also, if you can edit the css file or add css, to override the previous style, it needs to be loaded last , after every other css file or at the end of the css file.